# error in set labal value in java netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

This is my code in java netbeans. I want to display the username get  from another form in label and there is errer ...

```
 String username1; 
 public agent_menu(String username1)
 {
   this.username1=username1;
   System.out.println("user: "+username1);


    jLabel1.setText(username1);
   }
```

the error:

```
user: 22
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Answer (score 0):

Your jLabel1 is most likely not initialized. It prints out to the console what you expect then you receive the null pointer exception when you call jLabel1.setText

Comment: I tried many times...but still error

Comment: Add jLabel1 = new JLabel() before jLabel1.setText(username1) and try it. It should resolve the specific error but might not give you the desired effect. You might have to provide some more info but resueman link would be a good starting place.

Comment: @ms1991 If that doesn't fix it, then the error is not in the code you posted. The only variables which you show are `username1` and `jLabel1`. If neither of them is null, it's something else.

Comment: but when I use this code System.out.println("user: "+username); the result is user: 22 but in I used labal it came error